# Fortran : Confusing variable naming

Tags: variables, fortran

How can I know if my variable name is actually
the name of an intrinsic procedure ?

Here is an example of program :

```
program test1

implicit none

    integer :: i, dim

    dim = 3
    do i = 1, dim
        write(*, *) "dimension", i
    end do

end program test1
```

But then I discovered that `dim` is in fact a function :

```
program test2

implicit none

    write(*, *) dim(3, 1)

end program test2
```

This is confusing. And gfortran doesn't complain even with
the `-Wall` flag.

How can I prevent that from happening again ?

Comment: This is a "feature".  If a language update of Fortran adds a new keyword, existing programs that happened to use that keyword as variable name don't break.

Comment: `dim` isn't the name of a standard Fortran routine, though it does occur as a named keyword argument for a number of array.

Comment: Use a syntax highlighter to see keywords, such as `dim`, and use an underscore, i.e. `dim_`, when a variable you want to use is a keyword--note that some operating systems do not like the underscore, so be prepared for alternatives (like `dims`).

Comment: The trailing underscore, as @KyleKanos proposes, is valid in Fortran names so nuts to the o/s, any compiler which claims to be standard conforming allows this.

Comment: Truth be told, I have only *heard* that some OSes do not like the underscore; I have yet to see one that actually does not like it. As another alternative, one can always use Hungarian notation (integers are `iDim`, reals are `spDim` or `dpDim` or `qpDim`, logicals are `lDim` and so on)

Comment: Ahh yes @KyleKanos, the old approach of determining the type of a variable from the initial letter of the variable's name.  Didn't that go out of fashion :-)

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't think Hungarian notation should be used to prefix the type (you can always `grep` for that). Here's a good article on using Hungarian notation: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: I made HN my second suggestion because it is not really ideal (though I do use it for logicals b/c writing `IF(lGravity) CALL Gravity()` makes a lot of sense to me). Trailing underscores is my #1 choice for avoiding intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this in the future you can  check a list of keywords in FORTRAN.  Maybe familiarize yourself with some  more of them. [Here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Keywords) is a mostly complete list of them.  I am not familiar with any compiler flags that would help you however.

Edit,  also see first comment on this answer

Comment: There's also the list of [Intrinsic Procedures](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Intrinsic+procedures) at the same web site, which does list `dim`, unlike the keywords page.

Comment: Note that Fortran will allow all sorts of things that you may find confusing like allowing spaces in variable/subroutine/function names, allowing reserved words as variable/subroutine/common block names.  Just don't think too much about it and you won't find it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no such compiler flags on any Fortran compilers, because this is within the standard.  Unless things have changed, Fortran has NO RESERVED WORDS.  So it is perfectly permissible to have an INTEGER variable named REAL and a DOUBLE PRECISION variable named ENDDO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit your `~/.vimrc` file and highlight all `Keywords` and `intrinsic procedure` to differ from other variables' name